# When creating a dataframe in pyspark, records with a proper boolean value cause entire row to be null

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

Any time the boolean field is defined properly, all fields in the record become null.  The is the exact opposite of the behaviour I would expect.  Please, someone, help explain this insanity...

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, BooleanType

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Write parquet").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext

schema = StructType([
    StructField("sometext", StringType(), True),
    StructField("mybool", BooleanType(), True)
    ]
)

payload = [
    {"sometext": "works when mybool isn't None, true or false", "mybool": "not_a_boolean"},
    {"sometext": "returns empty when mybool is true", "mybool": True},
    {"sometext": "returns empty when mybool is false", "mybool": False},
    {"sometext": "returns empty when mybool is None", "mybool": None}]
events = sc.parallelize(payload)

df_with_schema = spark.read.schema(schema).json(events)
df_with_schema.show()
```

yields:

```
+--------------------+------+
|            sometext|mybool|
+--------------------+------+
|works when mybool...|  null|
|                null|  null|
|                null|  null|
|                null|  null|
+--------------------+------+
```